# What were the first words spoken by Adam?

Tags: creation, speech-talking, adam

What were the first words spoken by Adam?
Is there any lesson involved in that?

Answer (score 3):

As @Asher mentioned in the comments there are midrashim that exist from before he speaks about Chava's creation (as mentioned in the other answer).

In [Bereishis Rabbah 17:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereshit_Rabbah.17.4?lang=bi) it writes:

> אָמַר רַבִּי אַחָא בְּשָׁעָה שֶׁבָּא הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא לִבְרֹאת אֶת הָאָדָם, נִמְלַךְ בְּמַלְאֲכֵי הַשָּׁרֵת, אָמַר לָהֶן (בראשית א, כו): נַעֲשֶׂה אָדָם, אָמְרוּ לוֹ אָדָם זֶה מַה טִּיבוֹ, אָמַר לָהֶן חָכְמָתוֹ מְרֻבָּה מִשֶּׁלָּכֶם, הֵבִיא לִפְנֵיהֶם אֶת הַבְּהֵמָה וְאֶת הַחַיָּה וְאֶת הָעוֹף, אָמַר לָהֶם זֶה מַה שְּׁמוֹ וְלֹא הָיוּ יוֹדְעִין, הֶעֱבִירָן לִפְנֵי אָדָם, אָמַר לוֹ זֶה מַה שְּׁמוֹ, **אָמַר זֶה שׁוֹר, זֶה חֲמוֹר, זֶה סוּס וְזֶה גַּמָּל, וְאַתָּה מַה שְּׁמֶךָ, אָמַר לוֹ אֲנִי נָאֶה לְהִקָּרֵא אָדָם שֶׁנִּבְרֵאתִי מִן הָאֲדָמָה, וַאֲנִי מַה שְּׁמִי, אָמַר לוֹ לְךָ נָאֶה לְהִקָרְאוֹת אֲדֹנָי, שֶׁאַתָּה אָדוֹן לְכָל בְּרִיּוֹתֶיךָ**. אָמַר רַבִּי אֲחָא (ישעיה מב, ח): אֲנִי ה' הוּא שְׁמִי, הוּא שְׁמִי שֶׁקָּרָא לִי אָדָם הָרִאשׁוֹן. חָזַר וְהֶעֱבִירָן לְפָנָיו זוּגוֹת, אָמַר לַכֹּל יֵשׁ בֶּן זוּג וְלִי אֵין בֶּן זוּג, (בראשית ב, כ): וּלְאָדָם לֹא מָצָא עֵזֶר כְּנֶגְדּוֹ, אֶתְמְהָא, וְלָמָּה לֹא בְרָאָהּ לוֹ תְּחִלָּה, אֶלָּא צָפָה הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא שֶׁהוּא עָתִיד לִקְרוֹת עָלֶיהָ תִּגָּר, לְפִיכָךְ לֹא בְּרָאָהּ לוֹ עַד שֶׁתְּבָעָהּ בְּפִיו, כֵּיוָן שֶׁתְּבָעָהּ, מִיָּד (בראשית ב, כא): וַיַּפֵּל ה' אֱלֹהִים תַּרְדֵּמָה וגו'
>
> Rabbi Acḥa said: When the Holy One blessed be He came to create man, He consulted with the ministering angels. He said to them: “Let us make man” ([Bereishis 1:26](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.1.26?lang=bi&aliyot=0)). They said to Him: ‘This man, what is his nature?’ He said to them: ‘His wisdom is greater than yours.’ He brought the animals, the beasts, and the birds before them and said to them: ‘What is its name of this one?’ And they did not know. He passed them before Adam and said to him: ‘What is the name of this one?’ **He said: ‘This is an ox; this is a donkey; this is a horse; this is a camel.’ [He then asked:] ‘And you, what is your name?’ He said to Him: ‘It is appropriate that I be called Adam, as I was created from the ground [adama].’ [He asked further:] ‘And I, what is My name?’ He said to Him: ‘It is appropriate to call you my Lord [adonai], as You are the Lord [adon] over all your creatures.’** Rabbi Aḥa said: “I am the Lord, that is My name” ([Isaiah 42:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.42.8?lang=bi)) – that is My name that Adam the first man called Me. He then passed them [the animals] before him in pairs. He [Adam] said: All of them have partners, but I do not have a partner – “and for the man, he did not find a helper to be alongside him” ([Bereishis 2:20](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.2.20?lang=bi&aliyot=0)). This is bewildering; why, in fact, did He not create her for him at the outset? The explanation is that the Holy One blessed be He foresaw that he [Adam] would complain about her in the future; therefore, He did not create her until he requested her explicitly. After that, “the Lord God cast a deep slumber…” ([Bereishis 2:21](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.2.21?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Comment: So the first word was 'this'?

Comment: I dunno I wasn't there :-)

Comment: Well I do trust the medrash. It just seems anticlimactic...

Comment: It's time to start work on that time machine :-)

Comment: @Shababnik I think the same caveat as Ezra's answer applies here. That it may be the first **recorded** words of Adam. Insofar as he was a prophet, and his communication with God is a function of his prophecy it is reasonable to assume that these were not his first words. In fact, I would not assume that any record of his conversations are the first words he uttered unless the text actually communicates such as being so.

Comment: @Deuteronomy if we are guessing, I will guess that his first words were "hineini"

Comment: @Deuteronomy my question is really whether the first words spoken have any significance. Seemingly, with the information at hand, there is none...

Comment: @Shababnik if his first words were inspiring, it would probably have been recorded. Possibly this might mean that his first word was disappointing?

Comment: @RabbiKaii it seems that there is no importance given to firsts ? Though he is called adam harishon... I suppose as you said, that there is no notable reason to mention his first words

Comment: @Shababnik did you mean to write "no" importance?

Comment: @RabbiKaii that's what I wrote...

Answer (score 2):

The first *recorded* words of Adam are found in the Torah, Genesis 2:23:

> And Adam said, “At last, this one is bone of my bones, and flesh of my flesh. This one shall be called ‘woman’, for from a man she was taken.”

Comment: Although the precise words aren't in the Torah, certainly he named the animals before he said that verse.

Comment: Does anyone talk about any significance in this first recorded utterance?

Answer (score 2):

[Zohar Bereshis 221b](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar%2C_Vayechi.28.241) says that from the moment Adam stood on his legs, all the other creatures feared him and followed him like a king. So he told them the words in Tehillim 95:6, "Come, let us [all] bow down and kneel" before Hashem our creator, and they all followed suit.

> בְּשַׁעְתָּא דְאָדָם קָאִים עַל רַגְלוֹי, חָמֵי לֵיהּ בִּרְיָין
> כֻּלְּהוּ, וּדְחִילוּ מִקַּמֵּיהּ, וְהֲווּ נָטְלִין אֲבַתְרֵיהּ,
> כְּעַבְדִין בָּתַר מַלְכָּא. וְהוּא אָמַר לוֹן, אֲנָא וְאַתּוּן,
> (תהילים צ״ה:ו׳) בֹּאוּ נִשְׁתַּחֲוֶה וְנִכְרָעָה וְגו'. וְאֲזְלוּ
> כֻּלְּהוּ אֲבַתְרֵיהּ

According to [Sanhedrin 38b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.38b.2?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi), Adam stood on his legs in the fifth hour and named the creatures in the sixth:

> א"ר יוחנן בר חנינא שתים עשרה שעות הוי היום שעה ראשונה הוצבר עפרו שניה
> נעשה גולם שלישית נמתחו אבריו רביעית נזרקה בו נשמה חמישית עמד על רגליו
> ששית קרא שמות

So it's likely the Zohar's episode took place first.

Comment: I suppose praying is a good way to start off. Though does "standing up" imply the first?

Answer (score 0):

See the Mishnah Berurah 1;8 that one should immediately thank Hashem when he wakes up in the morning. So I assume that is what Adam did.

Comment: What makes you assume Adam followed MB ?

Comment: @mbloch He was Ashkenazi, duh :-)

Comment: @Loani MB brings sefardi halacha all the time :)

Comment: @mbloch Adam had no yetzer hara at that point. Either way I think I answered the point of the question. We see that the first words SHOULD be thanks to Hashem.

Comment: @KehasMakovsky actually the question was what did he say, not what he should have said. But it was a creative answer :-> This being said, more seriously, there is a Zohar that Hashem taught Torah to Adam who taught it to his sons & so on - this is why Noach knew which animals were kosher when deciding how many to bring into the arch

Comment: @mbloch Actually, the question has a second part. "Is there any lesson involved?" And I think that was the POINT of the question.